# Unable to conditionally render components from .json/.ts file in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

This is the JSON file. I've already created a .text component which has a text field and a .radio component with a radio button.
Now how to display them conditionally according to .json

Here is the .json file:

```json
export const questions = 
[
    {
    "question": "What is you name",
    "type": "text"
    },
    {
    "question": "Are you happy",
    "type": "radio"  
    },
    {
    "question": "How are you",
    "type": "text"  
    }
]
```

Here is .ts file:

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {questions} from './questions';
import { RadioComponent } from './radio/radio.component';
import { TextComponent } from './text/text.component';

interface q 
{
  question: String;
  type: String;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-disposition-wizard',
  templateUrl: './disposition-wizard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./disposition-wizard.component.scss']
})




export class DispositionWizardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ques: q[] = questions;
  
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here is HTML file,  currently it displays both text and radio component

```
<p *ngFor = "let q of ques">{{q.question}}

    
    <app-text></app-text>
   
    <app-radio></app-radio>


</p>
```

Comment: You have it already as `quese`. Just `ngFor` over it and render whatever needst to be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over your ques array with an `*ngFor` in your template. See [ngFor Angular](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

EDIT: After your edit ->
So if I understand well, you want to display `app-text` component if question type is `text` and `app-radio` component is question type is `radio`?

You can use the `*ngIf` condition:

`<div *ngIf="q.type === 'radio'"><app-radio></app-radio></div>`

`<div *ngIf="q.type === 'text'"><app-text></app-text></div>`